# Typescript, accurately represent class method behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have few interfaces and a class which takes an optional options object:

```
interface asObject { a: number, b: number }

interface options { returnAs: string; }

interface IA {
    go(): string;
    go(o: options): string | asObject;
}

class A implements IA {
    public go(o?: options): string | asObject {
        if(o&& o.returnAs && typeof o.returnAs === 'string') {
            switch(o.returnAs) {
                case 'object':
                    return { a: 5, b: 7 };
                default:
                    return 'string';

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I get: "class `A` incorrectly implements interface `IA`".

If I try to overload a method:

```
...
public go(): string;
// Notice the parameter is no longer optional, ? removed.
public go(o: options): string | asObject { /* implementation as above */ }
...
```

Now I get: "Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation".

I know I can just remove the overloaded signature on the `IA` interface and remove the overloaded method on `A` class:

```
// Interface IA, notice the parameter is now optional, ? added.
go(o?: options): string | asObject;
// Class A
public go(o?: options): string | asObject { /* implementation as above */ }
```

**Let me explain:**

The `A` class have a method called `go`, if `go` won't be provided with options object it will return a string, but if a user provides an options object, the return value depends on the `returnAs` field, meaning a string or an object.

**My question:**

I don't think the solution I provided represent accurately the behavior of the `go` method.

Is there a way to preserve the accurate behavior for the sake of typescript usage and not getting errors as I did with my first 2 tries described above?

**When I say accurate behavior I mean:**

I'm looking for a way where typescript will be able infer `AObject` type as `string`:

```
var AObject = new A().go();
```

And it will be able to infer `AObject` as either `string` or `asObject`:

```
var AObject = new A().go({ returnAs: 'object|string' });
```

I'm not 100% sure it's possible in typescript, in that kind of case I'd be glad for a suggestion.

Comment: Not sure, what are you trying to do. Why would you want to have object that `asObject ` and `string` at the same time? You can just use `else` instead of 2 methods, see [sample](http://goo.gl/motrsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to declare `A.go` result as `any`:

```
public go(o?: options): any {
```

Or declare function interface:

```
interface asObject { a: number, b: number }

interface options { returnAs: string; }

interface IGoFunction {
    (): string;
    (o: options): string | asObject;
}

interface IA {
    go: IGoFunction;
}

class A implements IA {
    go = <IGoFunction>function (o?: options): string | asObject {
        if (o && o.returnAs && typeof o.returnAs === 'string') {
            switch (o.returnAs) {
                case 'object':
                    return { a: 5, b: 7 };
                default:
                    return 'string';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually you do not even need to declare named interfaces:

```
class A {
    go = <{
        (): string;
        (o: options): string | asObject;
    }>function (o?: options): string | asObject {
    ...
```

Downside is that the function added to each instance of `A`, but you can explicitly add it to prototype:

```
class A {
    go: {
        (): string;
        (o: options): string | asObject;
    };
}

A.prototype.go = function (o?: options): any {
...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I really liked the examples and descriptive explanation.